# meaning of params in a image request

Tags: image, url

i found sometime image request are passed with prams.

what is the meaning of those prams?

let's have a example.

someimageurl.png?c=34

what is the meaning of the "c=34"

i found it in css, JavaScript file also

Answer (score 1):

It's up to the server that the image request arrives at to do something with any parameters on the image request.  There is no standard meaning of those parameters as they can be designed by the server to do anything they want.

To know what those particular parameters do that you're asking about, one would either have to reverse engineer it by looking at the whole application and seeing how they are being used in that application (and try to figure it out) or would have to see the actual server code to see what it does with them.

Comment: ok according to your ans. if i want a png in different size by the params ?s=256. image file can get this value 256?

Comment: @roconmachine - that isn't what I said at all, but if you've looked at the site and tried a bunch of things and found that to be true, it could be.  Without seeing the actual site, we have no way of knowing.